# Radio Button Selection Sync Issue, Selection in One Question Affects Another

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, laravel

so i have a quiz page where it can show different value based on current state like the question, and answer option, i use radio button for answer option. So my problem is when i select the first option of the first question, when i hit next to the second question, the answer option of the second question got affected it also select the first option. im using react

```
const [currentSoal, setCurrentSoal] = useState(0);
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState({});

const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setSelectedOptions({
        ...selectedOptions,
        [name]: value,
    });
};
```

```
{item.soal[currentSoal].opsi.map((opsiItem, opsiIndex) => (
    <label key={opsiIndex}>
        <input
            id={`option-${opsiItem.id}`}
            type="radio"
            name={item.soal[currentSoal].id}
            value={opsiItem.id}
            checked={selectedOptions[item.soal[currentSoal].id === opsiItem.id]}
            onChange={handleOptionChange}
        />
        <span className="pl-5">{opsiItem.opsi}</span>
    </label>
))}
```

i have an example but using laravel blade view like this, but im confuse how to implement it in react

```
@foreach ($question->opsi as $option)
    <div class="form-check">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" 
           name="soal[{{ $question->id }}]"
           id="option-{{ $option->id }}"
           value="{{ $option->id }}"
              @if (old("soal.$question->id") == $option->id) 
                  checked 
              @endif />
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option-{{ $option->id }}">
            {{ $option->opsi }}
        </label>
    </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

In React, you can achieve similar functionality by handling the radio button states within the component's state. Here's an example of how you can adapt your code to React:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const QuizComponent = ({ questions }) => {
  const [currentSoal, setCurrentSoal] = useState(0);
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState({});

  const handleOptionChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setSelectedOptions({
      ...selectedOptions,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  const handleNextQuestion = () => {
    setCurrentSoal(currentSoal + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {questions[currentSoal].opsi.map((opsiItem, opsiIndex) => (
          <label key={opsiIndex}>
            <input
              id={`option-${opsiItem.id}`}
              type="radio"
              name={`soal[${questions[currentSoal].id}]`}
              value={opsiItem.id}
              checked={selectedOptions[`soal[${questions[currentSoal].id}]`] === opsiItem.id}
              onChange={handleOptionChange}
            />
            <span className="pl-5">{opsiItem.opsi}</span>
          </label>
        ))}
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleNextQuestion}>Next Question</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default QuizComponent;
```

This code assumes that you pass an array of questions as a prop to the QuizComponent. Make sure that the structure of your questions array matches the expected format.

In this example, the handleOptionChange function updates the selectedOptions state based on the selected radio button. The checked attribute of each radio button is determined by comparing the selected option for the current question with the value of the current option.

The handleNextQuestion function increments the currentSoal state, moving to the next question in the array.